Waiting time of customer in the queue, its cost per day and cost-benefit analysis for new recruitment
A clerk in a bank is capable of serving on the average 12 customers per hour who arrive for services at an average rate of 8 per hour. Assuming that all the assumptions of single-queue single-server are satisfied, you have to answer the following:
1)What is the probability that a customer on the arrival finds at least 4 customers are already waiting for their turn?
2)What is the average time  a customer has to wait before getting services?
3)The management is mulling over the appointment of another new clerk so that service time will reduce to 3 minutes per customer and additional cost of $\\\$100$ per day.
If the waiting time of customer costs $\\\$0.5$(half dollar) per minute, should the management have another new clerk? Assume 8 hours working day.
My Solution:
To address these questions, we can use the principles of queueing theory, specifically the M/M/1 queue model, which is a single-server queue with Poisson arrivals and exponential service times.
Given Data:

Arrival rate $(\lambda)$: 8 customers per hour
Service rate $(\mu)$: 12 customers per hour

1) Probability that a customer on arrival finds at least 4 customers already waiting:
The probability that there are $(n)$ customers in the system (including the one being served) in an M/M/1 queue is given by:
$[ P(n) = (1 - \rho) \rho^n ]$
where $\big(\rho = \displaystyle\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\big)$ is the traffic intensity.
For $(\rho = \displaystyle\frac{8}{12} = \displaystyle\frac{2}{3}),$ the probability that there are at least 4 customers already waiting (i.e., 5 or more in the system) is:
$\big[ P(\text{at least 4 waiting}) = P(n \geq 5) = 1 - \sum_{n=0}^{4} P(n) \big]$
$\left[ P(n) = (1 - \rho) \rho^n \right]$
$\left[ P(n \geq 5) = 1 - \left( \sum_{n=0}^{4} (1 - \rho) \rho^n \right) \right]$
$\left[ P(n \geq 5) = 1 - \left( (1 - \rho) \sum_{n=0}^{4} \left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} \right)^n \right) \right]$
$\left[ P(n \geq 5) = 1 - \left( \displaystyle\frac{1}{3} \left( 1 + \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} + \left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} \right)^3 + \left( \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} \right)^4 \right) \right) \right]$
$\left[ P(n \geq 5) = 1 - \left( \displaystyle\frac{1}{3} \left( 1 + \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} + \displaystyle\frac{4}{9} + \displaystyle\frac{8}{27} + \displaystyle\frac{16}{81} \right) \right) \right]$
$[ P(n \geq 5) = 0.1316872]$
$[ P(n \geq 5) = 0.1317 ]$
So, the probability that a customer finds at least 4 customers already waiting is approximately 0.13167 or 13.17%.
2) Average time a customer has to wait before getting service:
The average waiting time in the queue $(W_q)$ for an M/M/1 queue is given by:
$\big[ W_q = \displaystyle\frac{\lambda}{\mu (\mu - \lambda)} \big]$
$\big[ W_q = \displaystyle\frac{8}{12 (12 - 8)} \big]$
$\left[ W_q = \displaystyle\frac{8}{12 \times 4} \right]$
$\left[ W_q = \displaystyle\frac{8}{48} \right]$
$\big[ W_q = \displaystyle\frac{1}{6} \text{ hours} \big]$
$\left[ W_q = 10 \text{ minutes} \right]$
So, the average waiting time before getting service is 10 minutes.
3) Cost-benefit analysis of appointing another clerk:

Current service rate: 12 customers per hour
New service rate with additional clerk: $\big( \mu' = \displaystyle\frac{60}{3} = 20 \text{ customers per hour} \big)$
Reduced service time: 3 minutes per customer means $\left( \mu' = \displaystyle\frac{60}{3} = 20 \text{ customers per hour} \right)$
Additional cost: $\\\$100$ per day
Waiting cost: $\\\$0.5$ per minute
Working hours: 8 hours per day

Current waiting time cost:
$\big[ W_q = 10 \text{ minutes} \big]$
$\big[ \text{Total waiting time cost per day} = 10 \text{ minutes} \times 8 \text{ hours} \times 8 \text{ customers per hour} \times 0.5 \text{ dollars per minute} \big]$
$[ = 10 \times 8 \times 8 \times 0.5  = 320 \text{ dollars per day} ]$
New waiting time cost with additional clerk:
$[ W_q' = \displaystyle\frac{\lambda}{\mu' (\mu' - \lambda)} ]$
$[ W_q' = \displaystyle\frac{8}{20 (20 - 8)} ]$
$\big[ W_q' = \displaystyle\frac{8}{20 \times 12} \big]$
$\left[ W_q' = \displaystyle\frac{8}{240} \right]$
$\left[ W_q' = \displaystyle\frac{1}{30} \text{ hours} \right]$
$\left[ W_q' = 2 \text{ minutes} \right]$
$\big[ \text{Total waiting time cost per day} = 2 \text{ minutes} \times 8 \text{ hours} \times 8 \text{ customers per hour} \times 0.5 \text{ dollars per minute} \big]$
$\left[ = 2 \times 8 \times 8 \times 0.5  = 64 \text{ dollars per day} \right]$
Total cost with additional clerk:
$[ \text{Total cost} = 64 \text{ dollars (waiting time cost)} + 100 \text{ dollars (additional clerk cost)}  = 164 \text{ dollars per day} ]$
Since the total cost with the additional clerk $\\\$164$ is less than the current waiting time cost $\\\$320$, it is beneficial for the management to appoint another clerk.
I shared my attempt to answer this question with you. In my opinion, it is  correct. Is it correct?

With the new server, are you saying that service time per customer will be reduced by three minutes or to three minutes?

@prubin, With the new server, the service time per customer will be reduced to three minutes.

Check your second bullet under 3). The "new service rate" seems to be the old service rate.
